# How can I install Java 6 on a PowerPC Mac?

Tags: mac, java, osx-leopard, powerpc, mac-pro

I own a Mac Pro computer with a PowerPC G5 processor. In addition to having loads of RAM and hard drive space, it is also one of the few permanently placed computers in the house. As such, I want to use it as a Minecraft server. The server itself starts fine (I am using a [fairly old] build of [Bukkit](http://www.bukkit.org/)), but very few plugins will load. This is because they were compiled into class files that require Java 6, but the Mac only has Java 5.

So - what is the easiest way to get Java 6 running on a PowerPC-based Mac with OS X 10.5 Leopard? I am using Homebrew for my package management needs, so I would prefer not to use MacPorts or Fink since I have had bad experiences with those in the past (though if they are my only option, then I can deal with it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) has a beta of Java 7 for PPC, but has Java 6 only for Intel.

Note that neither Fink, MacPorts, or especially Homebrew would not have a Java package since they would all use the native OS X Java installation.

Comment: The Java 7 binary works, but unfortunately it didn't work with Minecraft. (I guess that's because it's a beta, or they broke a lot of stuff.) Oh well.